# Change the url display in which query string used

Tags: asp.net

when i click on gridview hyperlink field the next page open and the url is https://www.example.com//forumtopic.aspx?CategoryId=1 but i want to display the url as https://www.example.com//Forum/Maths where maths is the value of category id 1.
please explain clearly and also tell what value we give in navigate url in gridview hyperlink field.......

Answer (score 0):

Use any URL Rewriting techniques

see the search results using the url below

http://www.google.com?q=url+rewriting+asp.net

let me know if you find any particular implementation difficulty...